# Validate uniqueness of nested association in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Rails 4.2, PostgreSQL 9.3

Model relations are:

```
class Nesting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :configurator, touch: true

  validates :product_id, uniqueness: { scope: :configurator }
end

class Configurator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :nestings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :products, through: :nestings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :nestings, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Situation where I create configurator with product `foo` and then try  to update it to add product `foo` works fine. I get error `has_already_taken`.

But when I add two identical products at once validations doesn't work. How do I validate uniqueness of `product_id` in `Nesting` model in scope of `Configurator`?

My views are pretty basic:

```
= simple_form_for @configurator, remote: true do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :nestings do |nesting|
    = render 'nesting_fields', f: nesting
  = link_to_add_association 'add product', f, :nestings, class: 'btn btn-default'
  = f.button :submit
```

_nesting_fields.html.slim

```
.nested-fields
  .form-inline
    = f.association :product, collection: @products
    = link_to_remove_association f, class: 'btn btn-default' do
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
```

One of the quick solutions is to check uniqueness of `product_id's` in parameters in controllers action. But I don't like the idea that validation happen in controllers action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) on `Configurator` may help, but  I would add a uniqueness constraint to `Nesting`. In a migration:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToNesting < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :nestings, [:configurator_id, :product_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Also see:

[Rails 3: Uniqueness validation for nested fields_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482777/rails-3-uniqueness-validation-for-nested-fields-for)

[Rails - Validate Nested Attributes Uniqueness with scope parent of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416599/rails-validate-nested-attributes-uniqueness-with-scope-parent-of-parent)

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1572

Comment: Also I humanized error message like so in Nesting model. I added `save` method, call `super`, and `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`